# Phoenix Channels [warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" - How to Avoid Terminal Warning Message?

Tags: websocket, phoenix-framework, elixir, phoenix-channels

While *running* the [Phoenix Chat Example App](https://github.com/nelsonic/phoenix-chat-example) on `localhost` we are seeing this "noisy" warning:

`[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket`

[image: warn-ignoring-unmached-topic]

`code/phoenix-chat-example $ mix phx.server
[info] Running ChatWeb.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000
09:50:37 - info: compiled 6 files into 2 files, copied 3 in 1.7 sec
[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket
[info] JOIN "chat_room:lobby" to ChatWeb.ChatRoomChannel
  Transport:  Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket (2.0.0)
  Serializer:  Phoenix.Transports.V2.WebSocketSerializer
  Parameters: %{}
[info] Replied chat_room:lobby :ok
[debug] QUERY OK source="messages" db=5.9ms decode=7.3ms
SELECT m0."id", m0."message", m0."name", m0."inserted_at", m0."updated_at" FROM "messages" AS m0 []
[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket
[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket
[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket
[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket
[warn] Ignoring unmatched topic "topic:subtopic" in ChatWeb.UserSocket`

The warning just keeps being logged in the Terminal/Console indefinitely while the client is open ...

Tried searching Google / GitHub / StackOverflow / Elixir Forum ...   
but no *obvious* solution ...

If *you* know how to remove this warning, *please* share! Thanks!

## Additional Info

- OS: OSX 10.13.2 (latest)
- Elixir: `v1.5.3` (*latest*)
- Phoenix: `v1.3.0` (*current/stable*)
- Terminal: iTerm `v3.1.5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [client tries to connect](https://github.com/nelsonic/phoenix-chat-example/blob/6f0e357f9a5c0ad208bb038100b21b6b0eb92b83/assets/js/socket.js#L57) to this channel.

The [channel you do define](https://github.com/nelsonic/phoenix-chat-example/blob/6f0e357f9a5c0ad208bb038100b21b6b0eb92b83/lib/chat_web/channels/user_socket.ex#L5) has a completely different name.

Bring these two into correspondence, e.g. by changing `topic:subtopic` to `chat_room:lobby`.